# Write file as one user, access as another fails

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, aes

I have two programs, each of which are running as separate accounts, even though both are Admin accounts. The first one is a Windows Forms app that encrypts the file, and the other is a Windows Service. I have a file in which I encrypt from the Windows forms program using the standard admin account on my Windows 8 machine. If I write to an a location like c:\test.xml it seems to work. However that cannot be used in production where the Installer will install all this to a directory.

Then I try to read and decrypt the same file, in the same directory, with the second program, a Windows Service, running under a different account called "Admin". The issue is that i am getting an `Access Denied` error when I am trying to do a `File.ReadAllText`. Does AES Encryption use the local machine certificate store since I am wondering if there is a permission problem there?

The WinForms code (running under standard Admin account):

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "alphaService.xml");

// var fileName = @"c:/text.xml";
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XElement xml = new XElement("Info",
    new XElement("DatabaseServerName", txtServerName.Text),
    new XElement("DatabaseUserName", txtDatabaseUserName.Text),
    new XElement("DatabasePassword", txtDatabasePassword.Text),
    new XElement("ServiceAccount", txtAccount.Text),
    new XElement("ServicePassword", txtServicePassword.Text),
    new XElement("RegistrationCode", txtRegistrationCode.Text));

doc.Add(xml);

//using (var aes = Aes.Create())
//{
//    aesKey = aes.Key;
//    key = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key);
//}

string sKey = "LvtZELDrB394hbSOi3SurLWAvC8adNpZiJmQDJHdfJU=";
var aesKey = Convert.FromBase64String(sKey);

string encyptedText = EncryptDecrpt.EncryptStringToBase64String(doc.ToString(), aesKey);
File.WriteAllText(fileName, encyptedText);
```

The Windows Service code (running under an Account Admin):

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
eventLog1.WriteEntry(path);
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "alphaService.xml");

// var fileName = @"c:/text.xml";

string sKey = "LvtZELDrB394hbSOi3SurLWAvC8adNpZiJmQDJHdfJU=";
Byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sKey);

var encryptedText = File.ReadAllText(fileName, new ASCIIEncoding());
string xmlStr = DecryptStringFromBase64String(encryptedText, keyBytes);
```

I also tried running the Windows Form as Admin. I tried adding the user "Admin" to the file ACL but I get the same access denied,

Comment: I seems obvious but I will ask anyway - did you make sure that both accounts have permission to read the file? Can you log in with the account of the service and open the file in an editor?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the encryption/decryption and everything to do with access to that file.

Comment: Hmm, Daniel, I logged with the account of the Windows Service, admin, and I browsed with File Explorer and I can't see that file! Its not there. In the account, the file listing is in green. How do I fix this?

Comment: Fixed by logging in as Admin account and running both programs. Thanks Daniel!

Comment: When you mentioned that the file is not there I realized what probably is the root cause of your problem - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably become a victim of [User Account Control Data Redirection](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx). Since Windows Vista Windows does not allow writing to certain directories and will silently redirect any attempts to the per user virtual store. The file your application created probably ended somewhere under

> C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore

and the windows service is looking in the wrong place because it is running under a different user account.